# CSS in custom module not loading

Tags: views, 9

I'm trying to load a css file in a custom module, to style a template file I'm rendering. I followed the basic steps:

```
global-styling:
  version: 1.0
  css:
    layout:
      css/rr_users.css: {}
  dependencies:
    - rr_users/global-styling
```

and

```
name: RR users module
description: Generates editing pages for users
package: Custom
type: module
core_version_requirement: ^9
libraries:
  - rr_users/global-styling
```

I can't find out why this isn't working. It looks to me that I did it correctly. Also I already tried to look up a solution, but none of the found ones worked out for me.

I already tried to empty the cache etc.

Answer (score 0):

`libraries` is not a valid key for a module .info.yml file; that key is for theme info files only. The full list of valid properties is available [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/let-drupal-know-about-your-module-with-an-infoyml-file#s-complete-example.).

There are a few different ways to attach libraries to a page from a module, depending on the requirement and available context. Those different methods are discussed, with examples, under [Attaching a library to page(s)](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/adding-assets-css-js-to-a-drupal-module-via-librariesyml#attaching) in the official docs.

Given the tags on the question, [Attaching a library to a view](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/adding-assets-css-js-to-a-drupal-module-via-librariesyml#s-attaching-a-library-to-a-view) might be of most interest to you:

```
/**
* Implements hook_views_pre_render().
*/
function yourmodule_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
  if (isset($view) && ($view->storage->id() == 'super_awesome_view')) {
    $view->element['#attached']['library'][] = 'custom/custom_view';
  }
}
```

Comment: Sadly that's not working either, I changed the `yourmodule` into `rr_users` and did the storage->id() check on 'user_dashboard, which is the name of the twig file. I also put the method within the .moduke, as the docs tell you to '

Comment: I use the same approach all the time so it definitely works, make sure you've named everything correctly and are checking the right things (e.g. you should be testing against the view ID, not the template file name, in case those are different)

Comment: Ah okay, I managed to get it to work. I misspelled `rr_users.libaries.yml`, but I also had to do `['#attached']['library'][] = 'custom/custom_view';` in my controller method that renders that view. Idk why, but with that double approach of mine it works now.

Comment: You definitely don't have to add it twice (the system is setup to de-dupe anyway so it wouldn't do anything). Seems likely you don't have the IDs or something else quite right in the preprocess method if you're having to inject it somewhere else. But aside from some really pedantic arguments about where the code should be, adding in the controller won't cause any problems

Comment: Alright, I currently have it like this ```function nn_users_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    $vars['#attached']['library'][] = 'nn_users/global-scripting';
}``` which is in the .module file. Probably fine for now

Answer (score 0):

[Adding assets (CSS, JS) to a Drupal module via *.libraries.yml / Attaching a library to all (or a subset of) pages](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-modules/adding-assets-css-js-to-a-drupal-module-via-librariesyml#pages) shows that a module should implement `hook_page_attachments()` to attach its libraries to all the pages or more pages. It could also use a preprocess function, which is useful in the case the pages to which you want to attach the library use the same theme hook.

The method you are using is listed in [Adding assets (CSS, JS) to a Drupal theme via *.libraries.yml / Attaching a library to all pages](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/adding-assets-css-js-to-a-drupal-theme-via-librariesyml#attach-library-all-pages), which also says:

> If you prefer attaching a library from within your module you can use [`hook_preprocess_HOOK()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/9.3.x) or [`hook_page_attachments()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments/9.3.x).

Comment: The current version of https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/creating-modules/adding-assets-css-js-to-a-drupal-module-via-librariesyml explicitly says that you can add the libraries key to the info.yml file. It does not seem to work for me, but that's what's documented.

Comment: Only themes can reference their libraries in their .info.yml files; modules need to use hooks. This question is about a module, for which the answer is *Use either `hook_preprocess_HOOK()` or `hook_page_attachments()`.*

Comment: Yes, it looks like that is a documentation bug.